# Definition of Limit Involving Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, inequality, definition

> Let $f(n)$ be a converging sequence in $\mathbb{R}$. Now, consider the following inequality involving limit
>   $$
> \lim_{n \to \infty} f(n) > a
> $$

My understanding for the expression above is that there exists an integer $N$ such that for all $n \geq N$, we have $f(n) > a$.

Am I unwrapping the definition correct?

Comment: The meaning of the above statement is that there exists some positive number $k$ (which is not unique) and a positive integer $N$ such that $f(n) >a+k$ for all $n\geq N$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What that inequality *means* is that the number $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)$ is greater than the number $a$. But, in fact, it can be proved that this occurs if and only if, for some number $a'>a$,$$(\exists N\in\mathbb N)(\forall n\in\mathbb N):n\geqslant N\implies f(n)>a'.$$But this is something that has to proved; it is not a trivial consequence of the definition of limit (although it is not hard to prove).

Comment: Your statement may hold even when limit of $f(n) $ equals $a$ for example $f(n) =1/n,a=0$. The correct version is in my comment to the question.

Comment: This is false as stated. One direction is obviously true: if $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)>a$, then $f(n)>a$ from some point on. However, the converse statement is false: we have $1/n>0$ for every $n>0$, but it is false that $\lim_{n\to\infty} 1/n>0$.

Comment: @egreg I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: Still incorrect, sorry.

Comment: @egreg And I am sorry for wasting your time. I suppose that it is correct now.

Comment: Now it's correct. One can take $a'$ the mid point between $a$ and the limit of the sequence.